# What did Mrs. Lippett say to her?

Tags: meaning, daddy-long-legs, jean-webster

> In imagination she followed first one equipage then another to the big houses dotted along the hillside. She pictured herself in a fur coat and a velvet hat trimmed with feathers leaning back in the seat and nonchalantly murmuring “Home” to the driver. But on the door-sill of her home the picture grew blurred.
>
> Jerusha had an imagination— **an imagination, Mrs. Lippett told her, that would get her into trouble if she did n’t take care—but keen as it was,** it could not carry her beyond the front porch of the houses she would enter.

This is from "Daddy-Long-Legs".

Answer (score 4):

The  answer to your question is not  immediately evident and  lies below the surface as I shall explain.

First the brief answer to your question : Mrs Lippet told her ( Judy ) that letting her imagination run free could only lead to future adverse consequences which proves to be an **untruth**!

Now for some explanatory background from the novel itself :You're quoting from the first chapter in which we are introduced to our orphan protagonist: Jerusha Abbott who prefers to be called   ‘Judy’ and lives at the John Greir orphanage  .The first Wednesday of the month is when the Trustees of the said  orphanage have their monthly meeting on site .We encounter ‘Judy’  as the meeting is [concluding](https://archive.org/details/daddylonglegs0000jean/page/6/mode/1up?view=theater) and  the various well to do trustees are dispersing and entering their waiting parked cars and carriages as they go home. Judy watching the scene  imagines herself travelling home  as they order their drivers home ( her imagination fails her when they reach the threshold of their homes as Judy has  never in her life left the orphanage to visit anyone at home) .

Now, the chapter from which the quotation is taken is entitled “ Blue Wednesday” .’Blue Wednesday” as becomes apparent in the chapter is also the title of a witty and humorous essay written by  Judy concerning the John Grier orphanage .This composition  has piqued her  Rhetoric teacher's interest and was therefore considered worthy of mention during the trustees meeting that Wednesday.This leads one of the most affluent trustees being sufficiently impressed and committing to provide for and fund a college education for Judy.So- far from leading her into trouble- her imagination  -it is clear - has [opened](https://archive.org/details/daddylonglegs0000jean/page/13/mode/1up?view=theater) up an amazing opportunity which she might not otherwise ever had access to !

So, Mrs Lippett’s dire prediction about her imagination leading her into trouble is proved fulsomely false in the most exciting, amazing and delightful  way for Judy and it carries her well beyond the confines of her orphanage into the world of college /university and beyond !

Comment: Very interesting, but I think the question was about what the reported speech indicated that Mrs Lippett had actually said.

Comment: @Kate Bunting : My thinking on the question is this : It is true that the question (as it stands ) is about what the reported speech indicated what Mrs Lippett had said,but since what Mrs Lippett said was untrue the answer must needs indicate that and explain the untruth of what Mrs Lippett said . 
Otherwise the asked question is asking what Mrs Lippett said and answers itself  making it a redundant question, or alternatively to explain what Mrs Lippett said as quoted without reference to the content of the Chapter or Novel making it a misleading answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mrs Lippett had said to her, probably more than once, "Your imagination will get you into trouble if you don't take care". Presumably she liked to invent stories which an unsympathetic adult would classify as 'lies'.

Comment: The quoted passage shows Jerusha merely daydreaming. How does it follow that she has been telling lies?

Comment: I haven't read the book, but telling her that 'her imagination would get her into trouble' suggests to me that she sometimes invented stories that were unkindly described as 'lies'.

Comment: An alternative explanation was that she thought that Jerusha would dream too much.  She would imagine that she could attain things beyond her ability.